# Error 403 when I use the railway domain, but locally it works

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Locally I can make my registration request, however when I use the domain of my application on Railway it gives a 403

**Here is my security config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityFilter securityFilter;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        return httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).cors(cors -> cors.disable())
                
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))

                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions.disable()))

                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))

                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()

                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/pessoafisica/login", "/api/pessoafisica/register")
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/pessoajuridica/login", "/api/pessoajuridica/register")
                        .permitAll().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/pessoafisica/{id}").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(securityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEnconder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEnconder());
    }

}
```

[image]

Simply the implementation in Railway does not accept my registration post.